# Table of content from MSDN help

Tags: msdn

I whant convert msdn help to chm file. Usually table of content already exists in single html page. But in msdn help, table of content building by ajax and not presents completely.
How get table of content file from msdn help?

For example, I get documentation from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb418439%28SQL.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have linked to the SQL Server 2008 documentation - this can already be downloaded as a stand alone "books online", [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=765433f7-0983-4d7a-b628-0a98145bcb97).

Many other MSDN Library components can be downloaded in a similar manner.

Comment: How get table of content from Books online?

Comment: @Oksana - Download it, install it and go to the start menu item for it (SQL Server 2008 -> Books Online).

Comment: Apparently you do not understand me.
I want to convert msdn help or online help in the other help format, you need to do somehow learn to somehow extract this information, I do not just have to watch it, I know how to do it, but how to unpack it - in this issue

Comment: @Oksana - you do realize this is copyrighted material belonging to MS, so anything you do with it (in particular distribution) is not legal without their consent.